# q-table - inser action button for each row (Quasar 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

not much more to add beyond the title. i'm looking to add a custom column to a quasar q-table (laravel / vue3) that will hold row edit / delete actions

[image: current action col]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Define a new column in a `columns` array

```js
columns: [
  // ... other columns
  { name: 'actions', label: 'Action' }
]
```

2. Use a [`body-cell-name` slot](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#example--body-cell-name-slot) to render the buttons for this new column

```html
<q-table
  title="Treats"
  :rows="rows"
  :columns="columns"
  row-key="name"
>
  <template v-slot:body-cell-actions="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <q-btn icon="mode_edit" @click="onEdit(props.row)"></q-btn>
      <q-btn icon="delete" @click="onDelete(props.row)"></q-btn>
    </q-td>
  </template>
</q-table>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/KKqEgao)

Comment: ty sir! exactly what i needed. we're simultaneously going from vue2 / bootstrap to vue3 / quasar / typescript. well worth the time and effort, but... it's a lot at once

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly `:props="props"` does ? I did not find answer in you codepen either. `<q-table>` does not recieve any kind of props

Comment: `<q-td :props="props">` renders `q-td` while passing the `body-cell-actions` [slot props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots) (ie. object ) into a `q-td` prop specially designed just for that

Comment: By plain words - imagine that your slot content is a function (and in fact, this is how it's implemented in Vue) . You are giving the `q-table` component a function the component will use in it's own rendering process at specific time/place (in this case when rendering `actions` column content). Your function needs to know which row is currently rendered, if that row is selected and many more useful info your slot rendering logic can use. This is slot props - pieces of data the component decides to pass into your slot render function...